# Bundle browser library on node environment

Tags: javascript, webpack, server-side, quill

So basically the problem is described in a title. I'm trying to use a library([quill](https://github.com/quilljs/quill)) that runs only in browser environment and in my project I have two webpack configs, one for a client build and second for a server. After adding this library server build is failing because of [this line](https://github.com/quilljs/quill/blob/1.3.6/core/quill.js#L1). So the problem here is my webpack doesn't look at node_modules folder and not converting this line for babel. So I used `webpackNodeExternals` and added this file in whitelist. After that my build failing because quill uses `document` somewhere in its code, and of course `document is not defined` in node env. So far I tried `ProvidePlugin` and defined `document` from `jsdom`, but then somewhere in `quill` code base they are using `this.textNode = document.createTextNode(Cursor.CONTENTS);` and my build is failing again. probably because `document` from `jsdom`  is not the same as browser's `window.document`...

The solution I'm looking for is how to tell my server not to build this library and its dependecies at all, or somehow replace it with something else only in server build. I don't need this on server side at all, only in client build which is passing correctly

EDIT: Added webpack.config.js that used for server build

```js
const path = require('path')
const webpack = require('webpack')
const dotenv = require('dotenv')
const webpackNodeExternals = require('webpack-node-externals')
const CleanWebpackPlugin = require('clean-webpack-plugin')
const TerserWebpackPlugin = require('terser-webpack-plugin')
const StartServerPlugin = require('start-server-webpack-plugin')
const CaseSensetivePathsWebpackPlugin = require('case-sensitive-paths-webpack-plugin')

const dotenvPath = process.env.DOTENV_PATH
  ? path.resolve(process.cwd(), process.env.DOTENV_PATH)
  : path.resolve(process.cwd(), '.env')

const { parsed: envs = {} } = dotenv.config({ path: dotenvPath })

console.info(
  `Environment was read from '${path.relative(process.cwd(), dotenvPath)}'`
)

const OUTPUT_PATH = path.resolve(__dirname, './build')

module.exports = {
  name: 'webClient/server',
  bail: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production',
  mode: process.env.NODE_ENV,
  entry: [
    '@babel/polyfill',
    process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development' && 'webpack/hot/poll?666',
    './server'
  ].filter(Boolean),
  output: {
    path: OUTPUT_PATH,
    filename: 'server.js'
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
        exclude: /(node_modules|scripts)/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: 'babel-loader',
            options: {
              cacheDirectory: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development'
            }
          },
          {
            loader: 'eslint-loader',
            options: {
              cache: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development',
              rules: {
                'prettier/prettier': 'off'
              }
            }
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        exclude: /(node_modules|scripts)/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: 'css-loader',
            options: {
              url: false,
              import: false,
              modules: true,
              localIdentName: '[local]___[hash:base64:5]',
              exportOnlyLocals: true,
              importLoaders: 1
            }
          },
          'postcss-loader'
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  devtool: 'source-map',
  watch:
    process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development',
  stats: {
    chunks: false,
    colors: true
  },
  target: 'node',
  externals: [
    webpackNodeExternals({
      whitelist: ['webpack/hot/poll?666']
    })
  ],
  optimization: {
    minimizer: [
      process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production' &&
        new TerserWebpackPlugin({
          parallel: true,
          sourceMap: true
        })
    ].filter(Boolean)
  },
  plugins: [
    new CleanWebpackPlugin([OUTPUT_PATH]),
    process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development' &&
      new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(),
    process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development' &&
      Boolean(process.env.SERVER_WATCH) &&
      new StartServerPlugin({
        name: 'server.js',
        nodeArgs: ['--inspect']
      }),
    new CaseSensetivePathsWebpackPlugin(),
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
      'process.env': Object.assign(
        {
          SERVER: true
        },
        Object.keys(envs).reduce(
          (destination, key) =>
            Object.assign(destination, {
              [key]: JSON.stringify(envs[key])
            }),
          {}
        )
      )
    })
  ].filter(Boolean),
  resolve: {
    modules: ['node_modules', 'src'],
    extensions: ['.js', '.jsx', '.json', '.css']
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you show the build script(s)? Ideally you would build only the server, and then only the client as 2 separate script commands, if they do share dependencies, make sure they are isomorphic.

Comment: @PedroMaiaCosta yes I have 2 separate webpack configs for client and server, they are pretty much same, except client has `target: 'web'` and server - `target: 'node'`.
Added whole server webpack.config in post

Comment: I'm not 100% sure how webpack works, but I do have a very similar typescript built app. Are you able to exclude the browser code from the servers and vice versa?

Comment: See https://webpack.js.org/configuration/ try to create a `module.rules` that will exclude all the browser specific code.

Comment: whole `node_modules` are excluded but then babel can't transpile this code - https://github.com/quilljs/quill/blob/1.3.6/core/quill.js#L1